# How to upload video to mogondb using expressjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**I want to make an web app where user able to upload to upload.
So how can i make the api where the video will be stored in mongodb.**

Comment: I wouldnt recommend to store videos in mongodb directly. You should rather store them in a BLOB storage like AWS S3 and only save the links to that in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Storing an entire file is not an option, you can store using binary data, but is not the best approach.

As Kris said, are better options like AWS S3. On the other hand, remember the limitation of 16MB per document, that is the maximum amount of data a document can store, so in case you decide to use binary data to store your videos you need having in mind this limit.